# Spring Boot is throwing a null for JPA Repository if I use the quartz scheduler to start manually

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm having a Quartz Scheduler as part of a Spring boot application. I'm loading the SchedulerFactory from a `@Configuration` file. This is the setup I have:

Config.java:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean(name="stdSchedulerFactory_api")
    public StdSchedulerFactory getStdSchedulerFactory() throws SchedulerException{
        return new StdSchedulerFactory("/etc/quartz.properties");
    }   

}
```

The quartz.properties file contains location to a file containing the list of jobs to perform. This is how it is configured in the properties file:

```
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames =/etc/quartz-config.xml
```

And the quartz-config.xml has the jobs listed as below:

```
         <job>
            <name>MasterScheduleJob</name>
            <group>MasterScheduleJobGroup</group>
            <description>This is Master Job Scheduler</description>
            <job-class>com.MasterScheduler</job-class>
            <durability>true</durability>
            <recover>false</recover>
        </job>
```

Master.java

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class Master {
    @PostConstruct
    public static void init(){
         // Get SchedulerFactory context from Config file and start the scheduler
         SchedulerFactory factory = null;
         factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) context.getBean("stdSchedulerFactory_api");
         scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
         setScheduler(scheduler);
         scheduler.start();
    }
}
```

When the Master starts, it reads the Quartz-config.xml file, and in turn calls the MasterScheduler.java which is below:

MasterScheduler.java

```
@Service
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MasterScheduler implements Job {   
    @Autowired
    public JobsScheduleRepository jobsScheduleRepository;
    private List<JobsScheduleDAO> jobsScheduleDAO;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) {
       jobsScheduleDAO = jobsScheduleRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get a null pointer exception saying jobsScheduleRepository is null. I'm suspecting this is because the Quartz scheduler starts MasterScheduler.java using new() internally. I do not want to use the Quartz scheduler provided by Spring. Is there any other alternative?

If there is a way to avoid using `@Autowired` and access the repository directly, I can use that as a temporary fix for now.

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough information to help you. You should add the full error output, and describe what steps you've taken to debug this. This helps people not make the same attempts as you, and helps us help you more quickly.

Comment: @Nashenas Sorry, this was my first post. I have edited my question.

Comment: No worries. It should be easy for someone with background on these technologies to help you out. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the frameworks you're using. These usually don't stay unanswered for very long. You should also add the Java tag.